# remove duplicates from SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like

```
col1     col2      col3
 x         y       0.1
 y         x       0.1
 y         z       0.2
 z         y       0.2

.......
```

(x,y,0.1) is equivalent to (y,x,0.1) therefore one of them has to be removed.

Basically the table is like a matrix. I need to get rid of all the entries which are above/below the diagonal of the matrix. The table has 100mil entries => the result will have 50mil entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you know that both entries are there, you can do:

```
delete from t
    where col1 > col2;
```

If some of them might already be missing and you want to keep the other one:

```
delete from t
   where col1 > col2 and
         exists (select 1
                 from (select 1
                       from t t2
                       where t2.y = t.x and t2.x = t.y
                      )
                )
```

The "double" `select` is a hack to get around the limitation in MySQL that you cannot directly reference the modified table in subqueries used in `delete`.

EDIT:

As Ypercube points out, the join clause is perhaps better:

```
delete t
    from t join
         t t2
         on t2.y = t.x and t2.x = t.y and
            t.y > t.x;
```

I actually find the `in` easier to understand.

Comment: You can use a join in the `from` clause of the `delete`. Much better than the double nesting hack.

Comment: col1 and col2 are foreign keys and not necessarily every entry has a "duplicate"..

Answer (score 1):

Try multiple-table [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

The syntax is not easy. Something like that (assuming your table is named `tbl`):

```
DELETE tbl FROM tbl, tbl AS t2
    WHERE tbl.col1 = t2.col2 
        AND tbl.col2 = t2.col1 
        AND tbl.col3 = t2.col3
        AND tbl.col1 > tbl.col2
```

Comment: It'll delete all rows as far I understand..!!

Comment: @user2407394 I forgot the `tbl.col1 > tbl.col2` part. As far I have tested it, it removes one line for each pair having col1,col2 swapped. Leave orphan lines untouched.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Sylvain should work. Here is an alternative using SubQ.

```
delete from mytable where (col1,col2)in(sel col2,col1 from mytable where col1>col2);
```